# Zoom out an entire viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm looking to zoom out an entire viewpager (it'll look more like a filmstrip), not the individual items, in response to an event.

What should I be looking at here? I'm having trouble coming up with a cogent way of doing this that smoothly animates to one view on screen at a time to, say, 3 views on screen (let's assume for now that I'm just looking to show the offscreen views, and make that variable a bit easier). Simply setting the page width of the PagerAdapter won't animate smoothly, right?

Has anyone tried to do this before? What did/didn't work out well?

Edit: I see that the Jellybean camera app does something similar when you swipe right (zooms out, shows more than one thing on screen at a time) - haven't found where this is set up in the source yet (is the source available for this part of Android?)